# Bash like installation suggestion in tcsh

Tags: command-line, execute-command, tcsh

In a bash shell, if you put some command that is not installed on your system, it throws an error and also gives you a package installation suggestion. For example-

```
$ iostat

Command 'iostat' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install sysstat
```

My personal favorite is tcsh but it does not give any package installation suggestion while some command is not found. How can I get the package installation suggestion (like bash) in tcsh?

Answer (score 0):

The magic works because of `command_not_found` **package** that provide a `command_not_found_handle` function for both **bash** and **zsh**.

This works in **bash** because of this *snippet* in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

```bash
# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
        function command_not_found_handle {
                # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                else
                   printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
                   return 127
                fi
        }
fi
```

There is also a file `/etc/zsh_command_not_found` that you can source to get that behavior for **zsh** - here, the function is called `command_not_found_handler`.

From a quick search, it does not seem that **tcsh** include such a functionnality to define a `command_not_found_handle`. So may be the name, is different, in that case you just need to convert the snippet in **tcsh** and include it in your `~/.tcshrc`, else you can't!